# Надо вычесть время из даты согласно часовому поясу посетителя

Tags: python, datetime

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть таблица со столбцами, в одном столбце дата и время визита записанные в поясе GMT+2, в другом часовой пояс посетителя, варьируется от GMT-5 до GMT-8, мне надо создать столбец в котором дата и время визита будут согласно часовому поясу посетителя. Пытался в часовом поясе выделить число и вычесть его с даты:

```
df['new_date'] = [(df['date'] - datetime.timedelta(hours=(i+2))) for i in df['hour']]
```

Получаю ошибку

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 492. KiB for an array with shape (62976,) and data type int64

Comment: В каком виде у вас хранятся данные? В базе данных, или еще как-то?

Comment: таблицу выгрузил в питон из базы данных да

Comment: Это не часовые пояса, это просто смещения

Comment: Какая именно база данных? И какой формат у этих столбцов в базе данных? Вероятно что ваша задача решается силами SQL, без питона.

Comment: А нет это с Яндекс.Метрики выгрузка